# Use computed field to calculate Field collection

Tags: entities

I have a field collection named values. It contains the fields:

- Amount
- Price
- Total

The "Total" field calculates the Price*Amount.

Now I created a new field *outside* the field collection called "Subtotal".

How do I sum all the values of the "Total" field in a node to populate "Subtotal"?
I tried a lot of code which I found but none seem to work.

I tried this code but it gives as a warning: undefined index at line 5

```
$field_items = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_values');
$total = 0;
foreach ($field_items as $item)
{
  $total += $item['field_total']['und'][0]['value'];
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $total;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see some typos/mistakes in your code. You missed to mention `$` for `total` variable (at line 2). and there should be `field_total` (I guess) instead of `field_amount`.(line 1)

Comment: Hi! I made some mistakes in the posted code. I hope it is clear now. So my field collection field_values contains a field field_total where I need the sum off. I found this calculation but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it! After a lot of tries I found a solution:
This works for a computed field outside the collection.

```
$sum = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_values as $collection) {
   $sum += $collection->field_total->value();
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $sum;
```